# Problem output result after summing values in BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to use while loop with If statements to store only 1s and 0s, then check which one is more popular than other.
I am encountering a problem when I try to execute the script:

Input:

```
bash vote.sh 1 0 1
```

Output:

```
vote.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
vote.sh: line 18: `done'
```

**BASH** code

```
#!/bin/bash
zeroSum=0
oneSum=0
while read num do
        if [ num -eq  0 ]; then
                zeroSum=$zeroSum+num
        elif [ num -eq 1 ]; then
                oneSum=$oneSum+num
        else
                echo only 0s and 1s are accepted
        if [ zeroSum -gt oneSum ]; then
                echo zero won: $zeroSum
        elif [ oneSum -gt zeroSum ]; then
                echo one won: $oneSum
        else
                echo it was a draw
        fi
done
```

Comment: Have you tried running your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ at all? You are missing a semicolon before `do`, an `fi` and several dollar signs to expand variables (and double quoting of variable expansions).  I'm also wondering how zero could ever "win" seeing as you only add zeros to `zeroSum` (well, you _would_ add zeros if you used `$(( ... ))`).

Comment: well spotted I will change them to add + 1 whenever one of them is read.

Comment: `I need to use while loop with If statements` .... why are you placing that restriction on the solution?

Comment: I have updated the question, with a better version, but I still cannot output the result

Comment: @jsotola because it is a requirement.

Comment: There are several things missing in the code even if you were to correct the syntax of the code that you have written. How many numbers should be inputted? Should reading of numbers end when there's an error or when a certain number of them have been read, or until the user presses `Ctrl+D` (as they would have to do now to exit the loop)? The second `if` statements seems like it should be _after_ the loop, don't you think?  What's missing is a description of the issue.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit where you've started to correct the code.  We're not really doing an interactive debugging section here. We're only trying to clarify your issues and then someone will summarize and write an answer.

Comment: @The_Liner are you writing a test? ... is this a school assignment?

Comment: I am trying to be clear, and yea there is no limit on how many numbers I input.

Comment: @Theophrastus that was a logical error I have fixed that.

Comment: It was not a logical error. It was one of many syntax errors in your code.

Comment: It was supposed to count 0s and 1s individually, I changed to +1

Comment: @Theophrastus I rolled that back. This is not an interactive debugging session.

Comment: The question is simple because I only need to count 0s and 1s individually and show which one has more popularity. That's it. If there were any extra requirements I would have added them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several syntax errors in your code.

The first one that is triggered is the missing `;` in front of `do` in the `for` loop header.  Fixing that yields

```bsh
while read num; do
```

There is also a `fi` missing for the first `if` statement.  Fixing this:

```bsh
if [ num -eq  0 ]; then
        zeroSum=$zeroSum+num
elif [ num -eq 1 ]; then
        oneSum=$oneSum+num
else
        echo only 0s and 1s are accepted
fi
```

Now the code *runs*, but since you've forgotten to add `$` to several variable expansions, you get more errors as soon as you start inputting data into the running script.

Fixing that:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

zeroSum=0
oneSum=0

while read num; do
        if [ "$num" -eq  0 ]; then
                zeroSum=$(( zeroSum+1 ))
        elif [ "$num" -eq 1 ]; then
                oneSum=$(( oneSum+1 ))
        else
                echo only 0s and 1s are accepted
        fi

        if [ "$zeroSum" -gt "$oneSum" ]; then
                echo "zero won: $zeroSum"
        elif [ "$oneSum" -gt "$zeroSum" ]; then
                echo "one won: $oneSum"
        else
                echo it was a draw
        fi
done
```

I've made several changes here:

1. The script is run by `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, since it contains nothing that `sh` couldn't do.
2. A variable expansion is written with a `$` prefixing the variable's name, *and double quoted*.
3. Arithmetic expansions are written as `$(( ... ))`.  Variables used in arithmetic expansion do not need `$` in front of them.
4. You probably meant to increment the variables `zeroSum` and `oneSum` by 1, not by `$num`.

This still does not make much sense though.  Why would you want to announce the winner in each iteration?

Also, in the question you appear to give the input on the command line, not on the script's standard input stream...

I would probably write something like

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

unset s0 s1

for arg do

        case $arg in
                0) s0=$(( s0 + 1 )) ;;
                1) s1=$(( s1 + 1 )) ;;
                *) printf 'Expecting 0 or 1 only, got "%s"\n' "$arg" >&2
        esac

done

if [ "$s0" -gt "$s1" ]; then
        printf 'Zeros won with %d against %d\n' "$s0" "$s1"
elif [ "$s0" -lt "$s1" ]; then
        printf 'Ones won with %d against %d\n' "$s1" "$s0"
else
        echo 'It is a draw'
fi
```

Here, the loop iterates over the given command line arguments, and when that is done,  the `if` statement at the end prints out the result.

In the loop, I'm using  a `case ... esac` statement (it's like a switch statement) because it's more compact than a long `if`-`then`-`else` statement.

Testing:

```
$ sh script 0 1 1 0 0 0
Zeros won with 4 against 2
```

```
$ sh script 1 2 1 0 0 1
Expecting 0 or 1 only, got "2"
Ones won with 3 against 2
```